# Erro ao renderizar ou dados obtidos de uma requisição GET usando Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, front-end, angularjs-directives

Estou fazendo um simples projeto de pókedex para treinar Angular. Consigo fazer uma requisição GET na *PokéAPI*, porém, quando tento renderizar os dados da requisição usando a função *ngFor*, os dados não são exbidos e o console apresenta o erro: `NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`.

#### pokemon.ts

Uma interface pra definir os tipos dos dados do pokémon.

```
export interface Pokemon {
  name: string;
  url: string;
}
```

#### pokemon.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PokemonService {
  private apiUrl =
    'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=151';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPokemonService(): Observable<Pokemon[]> {
    return this.http.get<Pokemon[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

#### cards-list.component.ts

```
export class CardsListComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemons: Pokemon[] = [];

  constructor(private pokemonService: PokemonService) {
    this.getPokemon();
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  getPokemon(): void {
    this.pokemonService
      .getPokemonService()
      .subscribe((pokemonReq) => (this.pokemons = pokemonReq));
  }

  showPokemons() {
    console.log(this.pokemons);
  }
}
```

#### cards-list.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons">
  {{pokemon.name}}
</div>
<button (click)="showPokemons()">Show pokémons</button>
```

No código tem um botão que ativa uma função onde eu printo os dados obtidos da requisição armazenados numa variável, o resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso solucionar isso?

Comment: O problema aí é que está pegando  o retorno direto da API e jogando na variável que é do tipo **array**, mas o que a API retorna não é uma array e sim um **objeto**, acredito que o que queira no HTML seja mostrar o que está dentro do array `results`, então basta fazer **`this.pokemons = pokemonReq.results`**

Answer (score -3):

Provavelmente o retorno da função `getPokemonService` não é um array iterável e sim um objeto de resposta da request inteira, incluindo outros dados do protocolo HTTP.

Tente colocar um .then nessa função e retornar somente o .data dela.

Segue a doc com exemplos de implementação: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get